# Can I obtain the full URL path of an endpoint inside WSO2 handler/mediator?

Tags: wso2, apache-synapse

I am using WSO2 AM 2.6, with two domains pointing to the GW host:

1. domain1.com
2. domain2.com

Is there a way to figure out, inside a mediator or a custom handler, if the API was invoked using domain1.com or domain2.com? Either a property or function that will return the following:

- Calling https://domain1.com:8243/endpoint/1.0.0 --> domain1.com
- Calling https://domain2.com:8243/endpoint/1.0.0 --> domain2.com

Looking at synapse properties, I see there are properties such as REST_API_CONTEXT and REST_API_ENDPOINT_PATH, but all return /endpoint/1.0.0 and not the complete URL, including the "domainX.com" part.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The hostname should be available in the `Host` HTTP header.

Comment: Isnt that depend on client sending this header? I am not sure any client whatsoever sends it.

Comment: As per the HTTP 1.1. spec, `Host` header is a must.